# Why is Mongo Dart not surfacing errors?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, dart

I'm trying to use Dart's aync programming with mongo model

I'm looking at the source for DbCollection and it appears the DbCollection.find() returns a Stream
https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart/blob/master/lib/src/database/dbcollection.dart

I want to turn a response into a List of Maps so im doing the following:

```
try {
  finder = await collection.find(query);
} catch(e) {
  print(e);
}

try {
  list = await finder.toList();
} catch(e) {
  print(e);
}
```

**Problem:**
1. Execution bombs out out collection.find
2. No error is trapped

**Question:** Is there a different approach to working with this api the i need to be using?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at package [readme](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart). There are some examples.

Something like this should do:

```
var collection = db.collection('user');
await collection.find(where.lt("age", 18)).toList();
```

But actually even with superfluos `await` it should work too.
I've made a simple example with your snippet and it work for me as is

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';
main() async {
  Db db = new Db('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo_dart-test','sample_test');
  DbCollection newColl;
  await db.open();
  newColl = db.collection("new_collecion");
  await newColl.remove();
  await newColl.insertAll([{"a":1}]);
  var finder;
  try {
    finder = await newColl.find();
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
  List list;
  try {
    list = await finder.toList();
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print(list);
  await db.close();
}
```